# Android: Default Battery Percentage Level for individual services to switch off

Tags: android, battery, batterylevel, battery-saver

We all know Android OS switches off services one by one when the battery reaches critical level. But is there any fixed battery level to cut down individual services.
For example, Bluetooth will be switched off at 20%, Mobile data at 15%, Wifi at 10%, etc. I am searching these information in Android documentation and Googling as well. But I am not able to find such information. Any help please.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what levels services turn off at, which is not a specific programming problem. You might try [android.se].

Comment: I thought programmers must have looked at android developer documentations and they might be knowing this information.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is set by the manufacturer.

I have devices that turn off bluetooth at 5% others 'die' while still sending

Comment: Thanks NikkyD. This is exactly what I am looking for. Can you please point me any document or manufacturer website that lists all the services and battery threshold level?

Comment: i dont think there is any.